# Вопрос по htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Я видел много подобных вопросов, но я не могу решить эту проблему с их ответами ...

```
Есть такой урл mydeomen.com/search.php?q=key+key+key
```

хочу чтобы было стало так

```
mydeomen.com/key+key+key.html
```